# Im trying to make a square root function in python

Tags: python

I know there are probably a ton of these but the ones I have looked at arent quite my question. I am trying to make a function where you It asks you "What would you like to square" and then I have raw input for them to type something in. How can I make it so I can just type in any number and it will square it for me. In these circumstances I can not use the ** thing.

My exact code. Its nothing special, very basic.

```
def square():
    print ("What would you like to square?")

    raw_input("> ")

square()
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the square or the square root?

Comment: square root. Ill edit the question.

Comment: Oh wait no its on the top.

Comment: This question is way too basic and it shows that what you really need is a tutorial on python. There are multitudes out there, and any of them would get you the answer to this in less than 20 minutes

Comment: Why not use math.sqrt after casting the value from raw_input to a float or int?

Comment: Aside: do you realize that "to square" a number, and to "make a square root" are different things? If you square 4, you get 16. If you take the square root of 4, you get 2.

Comment: What circumstance prevents you from using `**`?

Comment: Yes I do realise that. I will change that in my file. Thanks for pointing that out. Anyway, what could I add to make it square root things?

Comment: There are many algorithms for computing the square root of a number. I suggest you research them and pick one, because right now, your question amounts to "write the code for me."

Comment: I was asked not to use it. Im not sure why, maybe he is trying to test how well I know code. (It didn't cover those things in the book, hence why I am asking this question.)

Comment: Other guy answered. Thanks!

Comment: If this question is homework, then having us provide the answers for you directly is basically cheating on the assignment.

Comment: Please consider revising the question where it is more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to first cast the value from the user input to an actual number (`raw_input` returns a string), and then take the square root of that:

```
import math

def square():
    print ('What would you like to square?')

    user_input = raw_input('> ')

    try:
        number = float(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        print('You did not input a number!')
    else:
        print(math.sqrt(number))

square()
```

Comment: @Python, if this answer helped you, please select the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

[`math.sqrt`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.sqrt) is the function you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the return value of `raw_input` to a variable. The variable that `raw_input` returns is a string. The `sqrt` function takes a number as an input, so you need to cast your variable to be a `float`.

Here's an example:

```
def square():
    print("What would you like to square?")

    x_str = raw_input("> ")
    x_float = float(x_str)

    sqrt_x = math.sqrt(x_float)
    print(sqrt_x)
```

This function will prompt the user to input a number to calculate the square root of, and then print out the square root of that number.